# Dynamically add files to user data folder with visual studio setup project

Tags: visual-studio, installation, setup-deployment

I have a solution under which i have two projects :

```
-- MyApp -which needs to be deployed
   --Documentation
      -- file1
      -- file2
-- MySetup project
```

I want to add the contents of the Documentation folder dynamically to User Personal Data folder in the FileSystem Editor of MySetup project i.e not with AddFile from FileSystemEditior. I want this adding to be something like prebuild event for MySetup project.

That is because Documentation folder changes very frequently ( new files added) and I don't want to manually add the files to MySetup project, every time it changes.

Is this possible ?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Visual Studio setup projects. However, some commercial setup authoring tools offer direct support for synchronized folders. You can find a list here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software